# Как ввести целый текст через консоль?

Tags: java

Есть задача. Нужно ввести целый текст(с пробелами, переносом строк и прочее) через консоль.

`Scaner.nextLine()` только 1 строку считывает.

Если добавить всё в цикл с условием `hasNext()` или `nextLine()!=null`, что вроде как идентично, Текст вводится, но требует ввода и дальше, бесконечно.

Файл использовать нельзя.

Comment: Так и вводить циклом, для окончания ввода нажать Ctrl+D - это будет аналогично концу файла.

Comment: @insolor , а также не срабатывает следующий сканнер

Comment: Ctrl-D фактически посылает "сигнал" EOF (конец файла). Если не работает как вам нужно, то выберите какую-то строку, которая будет считаться концом ввода.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] text = {} , temp = {};
    System.out.println("Введите текст: ");
    try {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            temp = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().split("[/,;:.!?—\\s]+");
            if (temp[0].equals("q"))
                break;
            text = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(text), Arrays.stream(temp)).toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Проверьте введённые данные");
        return;
```